# Java using backward recursion for linked lists

Tags: java

So I'm try to find the position of last five from the End.

- compute the position of the last 5.0 in the list, counting as an offset from the end.
- if 5.0 is the LAST element, the position is 0
- if 5.0 does not appear, return a negative number
- you can write this using a loop or recursion, in any style, but you should only have one loop or recursive helper
- Hint: Use a backward recursion.
- Hint: If the number does not appear, return the distance to the END of the list as a NEGATIVE number.

Here is my code :

```
 public int positionOfLastFiveFromEnd () {
    return positionOfLastFiveFromEndHelper (first);
}
 private static int positionOfLastFiveFromEndHelper(Node i) {
    if (i == null) return -1;
    int result = positionOfLastFiveFromEndHelper(i.next);
    result = result -1;
    //if (i.item == 5) 
    //ans = ans +1;
    //return ans;
    return result;
}
```

I am not understanding why I can't get the position of `5`. 
My negative outputs are right put not when there actually is a `5`. 
Can someone please help me. Also I have to use backward recursion.

```
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd(-1, "");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (-2, "11");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (-5, "11 21 31 41");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (4, "5 11 21 31 41");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (3, "11 5 21 31 41");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (2, "11 21 5 31 41");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (1, "11 21 31 5 41");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (0, "11 21 31 41 5");
testPositionOfLastFiveFromEnd (2, "0 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 8 9");
```

Comment: 1) Your code doesn't compile.  B) I'd first learn how to use a debugger and walk through your code until you understand it.

Comment: I just fixed the complier issue.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, use this tutorial on how to use the debugger.  You can also liberally add println statements to figure out what the code is doing.  http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a variable `result` outside, initialized to the negative value as if there was no `5` in the list. Loop through your linked list without recursion, if the node equals `5` then save its `position` on your `result`. Since you will be overwriting this value, result will *always* hold the last `5`.

To get the index position from the last node (`result` has the index from the first node), just do `length-result+1`, `length-result` or `length-result-1` (it varies based on how you did your code), whichever formula returns `0` when the last `5` is the last node will be the one you should use.

Comment: I can't use anything on the outside.

Comment: the outside means the outside of the loop, not the outside outside

Answer (score 0):

You don't check the condition you are looking for, something like

```
if (i == null) return -1;
int result = positionOfLastFiveFromEndHelper(i.next);
if (result >= 0) { // five was found
    return result;
}
if (i.item == 5) {
    // return - result; position inclusive the 5
    return -(result+1); // exclusive
}
return result-1;
```

should do the trick

EDIT

haden't checked the definition of the return-value, 0 is the hit in the last position

Comment: This is giving me an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: did you remove your null-check, that wasn't intrended, sorry

Comment: Okay thank you, Can you explain though what exactly does the code do here : return -(result+1) and why does it return result-1. I want to be sure so I can understand for myself

Comment: `return result-1` is just the short of your `result = result -1; return result` which lets a non-hit return the negetive position to the end, negative to signal a non-hit. If you have a hit, you return the non-negative distance to the end. since you get a -1 at the last position, you have to ad one and change the sign `return -(result+1)`. If you have already a hit `(result >= 0)` you just push it through.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes so much sense! Thank you very much.